# Any way to ignore only "connection reset by peer" IOExceptions

Tags: java, sockets, exception, io

I am getting really annoyed with loads of IOExceptions from socket read calls due to network problems.   Normally it simply means someone killed the child process or the network went down badly (VPN connection dropped etc).

My server cannot do anything but I really dont want to see all these errors in the log files.   Is there any way in java to ignore these exceptions?

I know at the Windows msdn level its a WSAENETRESET error so why do all errors get handled into a generic IOException and not an ConnectionResetException.

Having a connection reset by peer is something which is very generic and standard.

I cant find out if the exception message will appear localised on different Windows OS locales either.

Comment: can't you just filter it in your logger lib? do you use log4j?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of adding a list of exception messages which can be ignored.  I would need to make this configurable so that customers can enter the localised strings though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [getMessage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage%28%29) method to see if the exception message is something of the sort:

> Connection reset by peer

This should not return a localized version of the error message. That seems to be done by the [getLocalizedMessage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getLocalizedMessage%28%29).

Comment: I didn't know about that either.  Maybe that does mean that the error is always "Connection reset by peer" then.  Now I just need to ensure that its the same error for nio too.    It appears that it may be "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" instead for nio.    :)

Comment: You should consider removing this answer, because it is wrong. See my answer for proof.  Unfortunately, I don't have a solution myself yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a solution in itself, it is just to prove that npinti's answer, which does sound reasonable, turned out to be inaccurate when I tried to confirm it, and is hence misleading developers to build solutions that don't work as expected on non-English systems:

**Contrary to what one might expect, `IOException.getMessage()` returns the same localized string as `IOException.getLocalizedMessage()`**.

When running this code

```java
try {
    client.read(byteBuf);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("IOException.getMessage(): \"" + ioe.getMessage() + "\"");
    System.out.println("IOException.getLocalizedMessage(): \"" + ioe.getLocalizedMessage() + "\"");
    throw ioe;
}
```

on a Japanese Windows, the output is this:

```
IOException.getMessage(): "既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました。"
IOException.getLocalizedMessage(): "既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました。"
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました。
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:245)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:353)
        at Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

On an English Linux it is this:

```
IOException.getMessage(): "Connection reset by peer"
IOException.getLocalizedMessage(): "Connection reset by peer"
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:245)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:353)
        at Test.main(Test.java:21)
```

Windows Java version:

```
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)
```

Linux Java version:

```
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, since the connection is reset, you can try connect to the remote in the catch block itself. So if you still cant get through , that means the remote system is still down and you can repeat this / handle this accordingly.
If this was for a very short time and you are able to connect now, you can somehow reestablish the connection.

Other way is to check by the exception content in catch block as described by @npinti