# How should "Connection reset by peer" be handled in Netty?

Tags: exception, error-handling, connection, netty

A "side effect" of using Netty is that you need to handle stuff you never thought about, like sockets closing and connection resets. A recurring theme is having your logs stuffed full of `java.lang.IOException: Connection reset by peer`.

What I am wondering about is how to handle these "correctly" from a web server perspective. AFAIK, this error simply means the other side has closed its socket (for instance, if reloading the web page or similar) while a request was sent to the server.

This is how we currently handle exceptions happening in our pipeline (I think it does not make full sense):

s, not the handler I have attached to the end of the pipeline.

**current setup**

```
pipeline.addLast(
            new HttpServerCodec(),
            new HttpObjectAggregator(MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH),
            new HttpChunkContentCompressor(),
            new ChunkedWriteHandler()
            // lots of handlers
            // ...
            new InterruptingExceptionHandler()
    );
    pipeline.addFirst(new OutboundExceptionRouter());
```

**the handler of exceptions**

```
private class InterruptingExceptionHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        final var id = ctx.channel().id();

        // This needs to ge before the next section as the interrupt handler might shutdown the server before
        // we are able to notify the client of the error
        ctx.writeAndFlush(serverErrorJSON("A server error happened. Examine the logs for channel id " + id));

        if (cause instanceof Error) {
            logger.error(format("Error caught at end of pipeline in channel %s, interrupting!", id), cause);
            ApplicationPipelineInitializer.this.serverInterruptHook.run();
        } else {
            logger.error(format("Uncaught user land exception in channel %s for request %s: ", id, requestId(ctx)), cause);
        }
    }
```

If some exception, like the IOException, is thrown we try and write a response back. In the case of a closed socket, this will then fail, right? So I guess we should try and detect "connection reset by peer" somehow and just ignore the exception silently to avoid triggering a new issue by writing to a closed socket ... If so, how? Should I try and do `err instanceof IOException and err.message.equals("Connection reset by peer")` or are there more elegant solutions? To me, it seems like this should be handled by some handler further down in the stack, closer to the HTTP handler

If you wonder about the `OutboundExceptionRouter`:

```
/**
 * This is the first outbound handler invoked in the pipeline. What it does is add a listener to the
 * outbound write promise which will execute future.channel().pipeline().fireExceptionCaught(future.cause())
 * when the promise fails.
 * The fireExceptionCaught method propagates the exception through the pipeline in the INBOUND direction,
 * eventually reaching the ExceptionHandler.
 */
private class OutboundExceptionRouter extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
        promise.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.FIRE_EXCEPTION_ON_FAILURE);
        super.write(ctx, msg, promise);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your intent here to send an error response to the client on some failures but not when the connection is closed? You can use `channel.isActive()` if you want to check if the connection is still active.

Comment: @NiteshKant That seems like something that is part of a probable solution. Sending an error to a closed connection seems like a bad idea, yes, so my only thought is to just keep silent. Do you not agree? I would like some input here. P.S. I just sketched how we _do_ it, not how it _should_ be done. How do you deal with browser closing connections nilly-willy?

Comment: The only thing you can do when the client abruptly closes a connection is to clean up your local state like if there is any async work that needs to be cancelled/errored.

Comment: Are you implying that you can know if the connection is closed before doing `ctxt.write()`? Because I usually just get the connection error on write. I _could_ prepend every write call with `channel.isActive()`, but that seems a bit bothersome (busy low level logic in application code), compared to just listening for an error.

Comment: And should/can I close or reset the channel when this happens? Not sure what kind of "netty side" cleanup I should attempt to do.

Comment: And I am still wondering what the "correct" way of identifying a connection reset _is_. I asked if I `should I try and do err instanceof IOException and err.message.equals("Connection reset by peer")`. Better ways?

Comment: @oligofren [Unfortunately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70222653/709537), comparing the message depends on the system locale. I am looking for a better way, too.